# smooth_compass show the default compass image for a second in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am adding a compass to my flutter project and I used[this package](https://pub.dev/documentation/smooth_compass/latest/). but when I changed the compass image to my own, it shows the default image for a second.
here is my code

```
 SmoothCompass(
          rotationSpeed: 200,
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          compassAsset: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/compass1.png",
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed:** this was the issue in compass package previous version this issue is now resolved in the latest version check it out [smooth_compass: ^2.0.4](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_compass/changelog)

1. remove previous version from pubspec.yaml.
2. execute flutter clean & flutter pub get
3. execute `flutter pub add smooth_compass`
4. now run your flutter app

Comment: thnk uh bro its solved